# Python Twitter API trying to retrieve tweet but error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, api, twitter

why am I getting an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'?
I am trying to retrieve a tweet using the Twitter API on Python. Full traceback here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/lol.py", line 34, in <module>
    headers = req.to_header()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 398, in to_header
    params_header = ', '.join(header_params)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 397, in <genexpr>
    header_params = ('%s="%s"' % (k, v) for k, v in stringy_params)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 396, in <genexpr>
    stringy_params = ((k, escape(v)) for k, v in oauth_params)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 163, in escape
    s = s.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Below is the code I'm using.

```
import oauth2
import time
import urllib2
import json
url1="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
params = {
    "oauth_version": "1.9.0",
    "oauth_nonce": oauth2.generate_nonce(),
    "oauth_timestamp": int(time.time())
    }

consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key="*********", secret="*********")
token = oauth2.Token(key="*********", secret="*********")

params["oauth_consumer_key"] = consumer.key
params["oauth_token"] = token.key

for i in range(1):
    url = url1
    req = oauth2.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)
    signature_method = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
    headers = req.to_url()
    print headers
    print url

for i in range(1):
    url = url1
    params["q"] = "pictorial"
    params["count"] = 2
    req = oauth2.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)
    signature_method = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
    headers = req.to_header()
    url = req.to_url()
    response = urllib2.Request(url)
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(response))
    if data["statuses"] == []:
        print "end of data"
        break
    else:
        print data
```

And if I change int(time.time()) into str(time.time())
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/lol.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(response))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Please edit your question to include the full traceback.

Comment: added the full traceback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"oauth_timestamp": int(time.time())
```

here you use an `int`, but that field *must* be a string.

Comment: i tried that but it still wont work.. added the full traceback :) on the post :)

Comment: You now have a different error. *look* at the values you are sending...

Comment: `str(time.time())` does not produce the correct string you need to send. Try `print int(time.time())` and `print str(time.time())`. Understand what you need to be doing, rather than by trial-and-error-and-stackoverflow-repeat.